# Calculate average difference in time taken to complete task in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

This is the [Sample Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W3pdH8Y16xnwETDsecBnQ5fY9ejyB3_A/view?usp=sharing) what i want to do is for each document (field "REQUIREMENT_DESCRIPTION") calculate time difference by subtracting the time in "ACTION_DATE" n row from n+1 row.
And then calculate the mean and standard deviation of each document validation time.

Answer (score 0):

So after searching online i found this formula which calculates the difference in time row by row.

First i split the column ACTION_DATE by "space" delimeter to separate time from date and than named the time field "ACTION_TIME".

```
Diff in Seconds = DATEDIFF(
                    Table[ACTION_TIME], 
                    CALCULATE(
                        MIN([ACTION_TIME]), 
                        FILTER(ALL(Table), Table[ACTION_TIME] > EARLIER(Table[ACTION_TIME]))
                    ), 
                    SECOND
                    )
```